# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

Tags: reactjs

Estoy estudiando React por un curso que encontré en YouTube, tengo el código exactamente como muestra el video y VS Code no me muestra ningún error, pero al cargar la página en Firefox y en Chrome ambos navegadores me muestran una página en blanco. El inspector de código en Firefox me lanza un error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, fondo, dinero, setTotal}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Alguien tiene idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, debes compartir el código, [mas aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de renderizar un **objeto**. No puedes renderizar un objeto, pero sí una de sus propiedades. Si ves, el error te dice que el objeto que estas tratando de renderizar tiene las propiedades: name, fondo, total, setTotal.

Sin ver tu código no es posible decirte donde está el error.

Pero, por ejemplo si tienes el objeto:

```js
let obj = { name: “Juan” }
```

En tu JSX **no** es posible hacer lo siguiente:

```
<div>
  {obj}
</div>
```

Si quieres renderizar una propiedad del objeto debes declarar cual deseas mostrar en pantalla:

```
<div>
  {obj.name}
</div>
```